# Cleveref with counters with same name

Tags: cross-referencing, theorems, cleveref, newtheorem

I am trying to use the [`cleveref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) package.

I have the following counters defined (hopefully this is the right way to do it!)

```
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
```

This works as I would like (i.e. Theorem 1.1, Corollary 1.2, Lemma 1.3, etc.)

My problem is `\cref` always returns Theorem 1.2, Theorem 1.3. I

Perhaps this is not right? (In my preamble)

```
\crefname{thm}{theorem}{theorem's}
\crefname{lemma}{lemma}{lemma's}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The behaviour you describe comes from the standard LaTeX `\newtheorem` command; the problem can be solved by using the `amsthm` or `ntheorem` packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}\label{thm:test}
test
\end{thm}

\begin{lemma}\label{lem:test}
test
\end{lemma}

As shown in \cref{thm:test} and \cref{lem:test}

\end{document}
```

The `\newtheorem` commands have to come *after* the loading of `cleveref`.
Additionally, the `cleverref` package has to be loaded *after* `ntheorem` or `amsthm`. 
In total this gives the following order:

```
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newtheorem{...}
```

By the way, the plural forms of theorem and lemma don't use an apostrophe, so you should use

```
\crefname{thm}{theorem}{theorems}
\crefname{lemma}{lemma}{lemmas}
```

Comment: thanks, I agree it works with what you have posted! Two strange things - (1) I have amsthm package loaded already and (2) I need to use \crefname, whereas it doesn't require you to? (I have split the file across multiple documents with \input{foo1.tex} if that makes a difference)

Comment: @Qwirk: using subsidiary files and `\input`, it's necessary to use the `\crefname` commands as you did. Do *not* use the `.tex` extension in the argument of `\input`: use `\input{foo1}` instead of `\input{foo1.tex}`. Delete all auxiliary files (with extension `.aux`) and compile again. If your problem presists, please add to your question a [minimal working example](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) illustrating the problem.

Comment: Thank you. I had to move the newtheorem definitions to after the cleverref package was loaded!

Comment: After wasting an hour - let me repeat @Qwirk's remark. The definitions of the `\newtheorem`'s have to come **after** the loading of `cleveref`!

Comment: @Dror isn't that what my code shows? :-)

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: By all means. I just wanted to stress the order's importance, since by overlooking it I managed to waste an hour or so...

Comment: @Dror Ah, I see; then, let me add this explicitly to my answer, so others can easily spot it.

Comment: Great example of how order matters in LaTeX... very counterintuitive. \newtheorem is associated with amsthm but a completely unrelated package has to be loaded inbetween one and the other.