# cleveref gets names wrong when using the SIAM document class

Tags: cross-referencing, templates, naming, cleveref

When I try to use `cleveref` in conjunction with the [SIAM style files](http://www.siam.org/journals/auth-info.php), references to theorems, sections, figures and tables are accurate, but all other references' names (corollaries, definitions, lemmas, ...) are replaced with "Theorem". Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[final]{siamltex}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

Here's a definition.

\begin{definition}
 \label{def:somedef} Some definition.
\end{definition}

If I use cleveref to try to refer to the above, I get ``\Cref{def:somedef}''.

\end{document}
```

which produces:

```
Here’s a definition.
Definition 0.1. Some definition.
If I use cleveref to try to refer to the above, I get “Theorem 0.1”.
```

A similar question was [asked](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19104/cleveref-with-counters-with-same-name) a while ago, and [the answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19106/440) was to rely on `ntheorem` or `amsthm`. I suppose I could get away with this by redefining all problematic environments (`mydefinition`, `mylemma` and so on), but is there a simpler or cleaner way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When several environments share the same counter -- as is the case for theorems, lemmas, corollaries, propositions, and definitions in the `siamltex` document class --- `cleveref` needs some help in order to figure out which one of the possible environments is actually being used for a given label.

The easiest solution to your problem, I believe, is to load the `ntheorem` package explicitly and then to re-run all of `siamltex`'s definitions of its five theorem-like environments. (Naturally, if you don't need to use all five environments in your paper, you can skip redefining those environments you don't employ.)

The following is a modified form of your MWE that uses this approach.

```
\documentclass[final]{siamltex}
\usepackage{ntheorem,cleveref}
\makeatletter  
% The next few lines are from 'siamltex.cls', but now with 
% \renewtheorem{...} instead of \newtheorem{...}
\if@onethmnum
  \renewtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
  \renewtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
  \renewtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
  \renewtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
  \renewtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\else
  \renewtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
  \renewtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
  \renewtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
  \renewtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
  \renewtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{In the beginning}

Here's a definition.

\begin{definition}
 \label{def:somedef} Some definition.
\end{definition}

If I use \textbf{cleveref} to try to refer to the above, I now get ``\cref{def:somedef}''.

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum** As Ahmed Musa has pointed out in his answer, the code I copied from the `siamltex.cls` file (what's sandwiched between the `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` instructions) seems unnecessarily complicated. For the sake getting `cleveref` to recognize the variants of the basic `theorem` environment, all that's actually needed are the following four instructions:

```
\renewtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\renewtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\renewtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\renewtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works indeed. I will need to make further modifications however, because the SIAM environments typesets theorem names and numbers using `\sc`.

Comment: Good. Why don't you post a follow-up question in which you note the additional issues.

Comment: I'm considering it, but I'm currently hesitating between that and simply dropping `cleveref` when the manuscript is ready, because I'm not sure the folks at SIAM will be too happy about a submission that redefines their macros (I know other publishers aren't, at least). Thanks for your suggestion anyway.

Comment: Getting `cleveref` to work does require redefinitions of some the environments of the `siamltex` document class. However, the appearance of the redefined environments is, by design, *identical* to that of the original environment. All that happens, so to say, is that `ntheorem`'s algorithms get involved and insert some extra (invisible) code which, in turn, helps out `cleveref`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know who made the siamltex class file but I was curious about the conditional in Mico's code. I had to find siamltex.cls (which isn't in MiKTeX or TeXLive), where I saw the original definitions. I don't know why the conditional there appears unusual. Please why isn't it as follows? The trace file is 20 miles long; I may save some time here. The following gave me exactly the output that Mico reported. In fact, I tried other things and there were no surprises.

```
\makeatletter
\if@onethmnum
  \renewtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\else
  \renewtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\fi
\makeatother
\renewtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\renewtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\renewtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\renewtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
```

Comment: I don't know, I suppose it's because they format everything differently (see my comment to Mico's answer).

Comment: I actually considered modifying/simplifying the code contained in `siamltex.cls` exactly as you did in your answer! In fact, the redefinitions can be simplified even further, by leaving out all of the code between (and including) the `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` instructions. However, in order to keep my answer focused on addressing the OP's concern, I chose to copy the code that's provided by the `siamltex` class and merely replace the `\newtheorem` statements with `\renewtheorem` statements.