# Theorem and lemma sharing counter with mdframed and cleveref

Tags: cross-referencing, theorems, mdframed, cleveref

## Problem

Essentially I've got the same problem described in [Cleveref with counters with same name](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19104/16923): I've got theorems, lemmata and corollaries all sharing the same counter, and when referencing them using `\cref` the text always reads “theorem”.

The main difference is that I'm using `\mdtheorem` from the `mdframed` package to set up my theorem environments. I like the way the boxes look, so switching to `amsthm` or `ntheorem` as suggested in [that answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19106/16923) is not an option for me. I even have `amsthm` included, but that alone isn't enough.

I've looked a bit at the sources. It seems `cleveref` provides a version of `\refstepcounter` which can take the name of the environment as an optional argument. So that should probably be used.

## Workaround

So one solution which works for me is the following: copy `mdframed.sty` and add that optional argument in the right place, which looks approximately like this.

```
 {%#3 given -- number relationship
    \global\@namedef{the#2}{\@nameuse{the#3}}%
    \newenvironment{#2}[1][]{%
      \refstepcounter[#2]{#3}
      \ifstrempty{##1}%
```

But this is an ugly hack. In particular, it means I'll have to update `mdframed` myself to keep this in the code.

## Question

I also don't see any such use of an optional argument in `amsthm` or `ntheorem`. So my question is this: do you know of any more elegant way to achieve what I'm trying to do? Can you tell how these two packages address the problem, and can I somehow port that to `mdframed`?

## Patching

Or can I use `etoolbox` and `\patchcmd` to get this working? I tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
\expandafter\patchcmd\csname mdtheorem\space code\endcsname
{\refstepcounter{#3}}{\refstepcounter[#2]{#3}}{}{}
```

With `\tracingpatches` the log claims that patching worked, but in fact nothing changed.

## Example

Small reproducing example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[textwidth=5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}
\mdtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}
\mdtheorem{Lemma}[Theorem]{Lemma}
\crefname{Theorem}{theorem}{theorems}
\crefname{Lemma}{lemma}{lemmas}
\begin{document}
 \begin{Lemma}\label{x}
  Mary had a little lamb.
 \end{Lemma}
 Now look at \cref{x}.
\end{document}
```

[image: Undesired rendering]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following seems to work:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[textwidth=5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}
\mdtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}
\mdtheorem{Lemma}[Theorem]{Lemma}
\crefname{Theorem}{theorem}{theorems}
\crefname{Lemma}{lemma}{lemmas}
\let\oldLemma\Lemma
\renewcommand{\Lemma}{%
  \crefalias{Theorem}{Lemma}% Theorem counter now looks like Lemma
  \oldLemma}
\begin{document}
\begin{Lemma}\label{x}
  Mary had a little lamb.
\end{Lemma}
Now look at \cref{x}.

\begin{Theorem}\label{y}
  Mary had a little lamb.
\end{Theorem}
Now look at \cref{y}.
\end{document}
```

We change the way the universal `Theorem` counter is represented using an alias. We have to sneak it into the `Lemma` *before* the counter is stepped (implying that the `settings` key is too late), so we update the environment opening command `\Lemma`. Since the alias is set within a group, the local change is reversed when outside the environment.