# Cleveref cref problem with counters: use 'theorem' for all other labels in new ACM template

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

The [new ACM template](https://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template) has introduces new environments like 'example', 'definition', etc. Now you can write:

```
\begin{example}
\label{myex}
Assume BLA BLA
\end{example}
```

and the output should be:

*Example 4.1* Assume BLA BLA

But if you use `\cref{myex}` to cross-reference it, that would appear with 'theorem' label instead of 'example':

```
In \cref{myex}, we explained BLA BLA
```

the output is:

```
In theorem 4.1. we explained BLA BLA
```

I don't want to modify the main `.cls` file, instead I'm trying to renew comments or so.
I tried a few tricks including [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175961/theorem-and-lemma-sharing-counter-with-mdframed-and-cleveref) but didn't work out.

**Update:**

The minimum compilable code:

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\Crefname{example}{Example}{Examples}

\begin{document}
\begin{example}
\label{myex}
Assume bla bla
\end{example}

In \cref{myex}, we show 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Normally `\crefname{example}{Example}{Examples}` should work (and is setup by default by `cleveref` already,most likely), but perhaps the theorem environments use counter names that do not match the environment. Please provide a compilable example instead of your fragments only

Comment: Of course I meant `\Crefname` above, for the upper - case names

Comment: "The new ACM template..." -- For the uninitiated, would you mind stating what the template is called and where it might be obtained from?

Comment: @Mico: Most likely it is this one: [acmart](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/acmart) and it has the other theorem environments using shared counters of `theorem`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I updated the post with an example.

Comment: @Farzad: Yes, thanks. It's the issue with the shared counters I already wrote in the comment to Mico. You can use `\label{example}{myex}` explicitly to overrule the counter that is used by `cleveref`. Do you need shared counters at all?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer It didn't work with overrule. I tried both `\cref{myex}` and `\cref{example}{myex}` and none worked. And I don't really need shared counters.

Comment: @Farzad: No, use `\Cref{myex}` or say `\crefname{example}{example}{examples} in addition to `\Crefname` (like in your post), you can use `\cref{example}`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer still no luck. It doesn't overrule, I get: `Example 0.1. myex Assume` and `In ??, we show`

Comment: @Farzad: Did you recompile twice? For me it works!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56313/discussion-between-farzad-and-christian-hupfer).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Solution** [suggested by [christian-hupfer]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/31729/christian-hupfer):

Specify the counter that you wish to use, by overruling it while using the `\label`. Like this:

```
\label[example]{myex}
```

Similarly, if you are using another environment (e.g. 'definition') you can overrule the counter like this:

```
\label[definition]{mydef}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you do the following:

- Find the file `acmart.cls` in your TeX distribution. (In MacTeX2016, which is the TeX distribution on my system, the file is located at `/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/acmart/acmart.cls`.)
- Make the copy of this file, and call the copy (say) `acmartclever.cls`. *Do not edit or otherwise modify* the file `acmart.cls` directly.
- Open the file `acmartclever.cls` in a text editor. (The editor you use for your tex files will do fine.)
- Do a global search-and-replace on the string `acmart.cls` -- there should be 11 instances of this string -- and replace this string with `acmartclever.cls`.
- On line 40 of the file, replace the string `\ProvidesClass{acmart}` with `\ProvidesClass{acmartclever}`.

  Similarly, on line 43 of the file, replace the string `\def\@classname{acmart}` with `\def\@classname{acmartclever}`.
- Go to line 2188 of the file and insert the instruction

  ```
  \usepackage{cleveref}
  ```

  immediately ahead of the line that says `\theoremstyle{acmplain}`. Why not later in the file, you may ask? It's because that what follows the `\theoremstyle{acmplain}` declaration is the group of definitions of a long list of theorem-like environments, such as `theorem`, `conjecture`, `proposition`, `lemma`, `corollary`, `example`, and `definition`. `cleveref` is clever enough to associate environments with labels even if all theorem-like environments share the same counter. However, in order to perform these clever associations, `cleveref` must be loaded *before* the theorem-like environments are set up.

  If you're in the habit of loading `cleveref` with some or all of the options `nameinlink`, `capitalize`, and `noabbrev`, you should either specify them now, i.e., write something like

  ```
  \usepackage[nameinlink,capitalize,noabbrev]{cleveref}
  ```

  Alternatively, and rather more flexibly, just provide some or all of these options in the list of options you specify in the `\documentclass` instruction.
- Save the file `acmartclever.cls` in the directory where your main tex file is located.
- In your main tex file, the first line should now read

  ```
  \documentclass[<options>]{acmartnew}
  ```

Happy TeXing!

---

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[sigconf,capitalize]{acmartclever} % note the option 'capitalize': it will
                                                 % be passed to 'cleveref'
\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{2} % just for this example

\begin{example}\label{myex}
Assume bla bla
\end{example}

In \cref{myex}, we showed that \dots
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ideally, in some future revision of the `acmart` document class, an option will be provided to load the `cleveref` package directly, possibly via a suitable option that may be specified at the `\documentclass[<options>]{cleveref}` stage.

Answer (score 2):

I've added cleveref to the list of packages used.  After this version becomes official the problem is resolved