# How to use autoref or cleveref when the theorem environments are in the class file?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, document-classes, cleveref, amsthm

The journal [LMCS](http://www.lmcs-online.org/) provides a style, [lmcs.cls](http://www.lmcs-online.org/Information/lmcs.cls), that contains definition of theorems environments :

```
%%% Theorem environments

% the following environments switch to a slanted font:
\theoremstyle{plain}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{asm}[thm]{Assumption}

% the following environments keep the roman font:
\theoremstyle{definition}

\newtheorem{rem}[thm]{Remark}
\newtheorem{rems}[thm]{Remarks}
\newtheorem{exa}[thm]{Example}
\newtheorem{exas}[thm]{Examples}
\newtheorem{defi}[thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{conv}[thm]{Convention}
\newtheorem{conj}[thm]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{prob}[thm]{Problem}
\newtheorem{oprob}[thm]{Open Problem}
\newtheorem{algo}[thm]{Algorithm}
\newtheorem{obs}[thm]{Observation}
\newtheorem{qu}[thm]{Question}
\newtheorem{fact}[thm]{Fact}
\newtheorem{pty}[thm]{Property}
```

They insist very much on the author using that style: cf. l.85--87 of [the example file](http://www.lmcs-online.org/Information/lmcs-smp.tex), saying

> Authors should refrain from […] changing the numbering style for theorems and definitions and the like, \eg, by redefining the already provided environments.

But even if I load `amsthm` (as [recommended here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19106/34551)), load the packages in the supposedly correct order (i.e. `amsthm` then `hyperref` then `cleveref`) and try `autoref` and `cref`, all my references are labelled with "Theorem".

MWE (that needs [lmcs.cls](http://www.lmcs-online.org/Information/lmcs.cls)):

```
\documentclass{lmcs}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\def\defiautorefname{Definition} % For autoref
\def\thmautorefname{Theorem} % autoref will use that definition!

\crefname{defi}{Definition}{Definitions} % For cref
\crefname{thm}{Theorem}{Theorems} % cref will use that definition!

\begin{document}
\begin{defi}\label{defi}
This is not that.
\end{defi}

The \autoref{defi}, as well as the \cref{defi}, are not definitions!
\end{document}
```

provides:
[image: The definition is refereed to as a theorem.]

Comment: If you are writing an article for that journal. How do you know that `cleverref` is even allowed? It might not be a part of their setup. Journals are often quite conservative.

Comment: Ok, that a good question. I have no idea if that package is allowed, but they insist on the author using labels and the `ref` command, so I guess that `autoref` is allowed. Anyway, you can think of that question independently of the process of submitting to that journal: what if I wanted to use that class for my private use?

Comment: I tend to use something a lot simpler than `cleverref` (as this shows it is a bit too clever). So I tend to rely on the very old `fancyref`, the caveat there is that the name comes from the label prefix, which is not that much of an issue when you have an editor that can easily rename labels and references.

Comment: since the document class already defines theorem objects, i'd be very hesitant to expect that adding `amsthm` would have any useful result, and think it may even cause unwanted conflicts.  (though i haven't tried it.)

Comment: Ok thanks for your comments. There is probably n satisfactory solution, so I'll just end up with "Definition~\ref{defi}", as they do in the example file.

Comment: @daleif I'm glad I'm not the only one who uses `fancyref`. (I do sometimes use `cleverref`, but mostly not.)

Comment: @cfr perhaps I should send you a copy of my xfancyref package? It can do more or less the same as the original, and is much easier to setup

Answer (score 6):

You can redefine the theorem-like environments *after* `hyperref` and `cleveref` are loaded, using the same scheme in the class.

```
\documentclass{lmcs}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newcommand{\renewtheorem}[1]{%
  \expandafter\let\csname #1\endcsname\relax
  \expandafter\let\csname c@#1\endcsname\relax
  \expandafter\let\csname end#1\endcsname\relax
  \newtheorem{#1}%
}

\theoremstyle{plain}

\renewtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\renewtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\renewtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\renewtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\renewtheorem{asm}[thm]{Assumption}

% the following environments keep the roman font:
\theoremstyle{definition}

\renewtheorem{rem}[thm]{Remark}
\renewtheorem{rems}[thm]{Remarks}
\renewtheorem{exa}[thm]{Example}
\renewtheorem{exas}[thm]{Examples}
\renewtheorem{defi}[thm]{Definition}
\renewtheorem{conv}[thm]{Convention}
\renewtheorem{conj}[thm]{Conjecture}
\renewtheorem{prob}[thm]{Problem}
\renewtheorem{oprob}[thm]{Open Problem}
\renewtheorem{algo}[thm]{Algorithm}
\renewtheorem{obs}[thm]{Observation}
\renewtheorem{qu}[thm]{Question}
\renewtheorem{fact}[thm]{Fact}
\renewtheorem{pty}[thm]{Property}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\begin{defi}\label{defi}
This is not that.
\end{defi}

As you see, \cref{defi} is a definition!

\end{document}
```

For `\autoref` much more work is needed, with `aliascnt`; it could be incorporated in `\renewtheorem`, but `cleveref` is superior anyway.

[image]

Whether this is acceptable to the copy editors I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why both `\autoref` and `cleveref` fail here is the shared counter `thm`, i.e. all defined environments use the same counter which is used as information both from `hyperref` to build the anchor (from which the `autoref` name is generated later on and as well as a misleading information for `cleveref`.

The `cleveref` problem is easier to solve, say, with the `\label[defi]{somelabel}` command or a wrapper named `\theolabel` which tries to extract the name of the current environment, which is stored in `\@currenvir`. This assumes that `\crefname` is defined for the relevant environment name.

A redefinition of `\hyper@refstepcounter` which is aware of the environment and the counter name pursues a similar strategy: Pretending the counter name is a different one. If the counter name is `thm` or any other counter, nothing unusual happens, else the environment name is used.

```
\documentclass{lmcs}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}


\makeatletter

\let\orig@hyper@refstepcounter\hyper@refstepcounter%

\newcommand{\thmcountername}{thm}% This is the counter name for the theorems as defined in the lmcs class

\renewcommand{\hyper@refstepcounter}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \def\temp@a{#1}% 
  \edef\temp@b{\thmcountername}% Which is the counter name
  \ifx\temp@a\temp@b% Is #1 = counter name?
  \ifx\@currenvir\temp@b% Is this the original environment -> do nothing special
  \orig@hyper@refstepcounter{#1}%
  \else% Now fake the theH.... and pretend it is a different counter
  \expandafter\let\csname c@\@currenvir\expandafter\endcsname\csname c@\thmcountername\endcsname% Ugly trick!
  \orig@hyper@refstepcounter{\@currenvir}%
  \fi
  \else% Any other counter%
  \orig@hyper@refstepcounter{#1}%
  \fi
  \endgroup
}


\newcommand{\theolabel}[1]{%
  \label[\@currenvir]{#1}%
}
\makeatother



\def\defiautorefname{Definition} % For autoref
\def\exaautorefname{Example} % For autoref
\def\thmautorefname{Theorem} % autoref will use that definition!

\Crefname{exa}{Example}{Examples} % For cref
\crefname{defi}{Definition}{Definitions} % For cref
\crefname{thm}{Theorem}{Theorems} % cref will use that definition!

\begin{document}

\section{Foo}

\begin{exa}
  Stuff \theolabel{exastuff}
\end{exa}
\begin{defi}\theolabel{defi}
This is not that.
  \begin{equation}
    E=mc^2 \label{fooequation}
    \end{equation}
\end{defi}

\begin{thm}\theolabel{thmstuff}
  This is not that.
\end{thm}

See \autoref{exastuff}  or \Cref{exastuff} or \cref{fooequation}

The \autoref{defi}, as well as the \cref{defi}, are definitions and not reported as Theorems any longer!
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think you should at least mention that this is likely to be unacceptable to the editors!

Comment: @cfr: I don't change the class file. If I built a ladder I don't put a sign there: 'Don't climb up'

Answer (score 1):

Since this question seems still to show up in search engines, let me answer it as someone from the LMCS team. Nowadays (in 2023 but already for a couple of years), `lmcs.cls` works well with the hyperref package:

```tex
\documentclass{lmcs}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{Tests}
\begin{thm}\label{mythm}
The theorem.
\end{thm}
\begin{defi}\label{mydef}
The definition.
\end{defi}

\begin{tabular}{@{}lll@{}}
Environment & autoref \\ \hline
Theorem & \autoref{mythm} \\
Definition & \autoref{mydef} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

So there is no need for `cleveref`. If you still insist on using `cleveref` you can do so via `\crefname` (without loading the `amsthm` package!):

```tex
\documentclass{lmcs}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefname{defi}{Definition}{Definitions} % For cref
\crefname{thm}{Theorem}{Theorems} % cref will use that definition!

\begin{document}
\section{Tests}
\begin{thm}\label{mythm}
The theorem.
\end{thm}
\begin{defi}\label{mydef}
The definition.
\end{defi}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
Environment & autoref & cref \\ \hline
Theorem & \autoref{mythm} & \cref{mythm} \\
Definition & \autoref{mydef} & \cref{mydef} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]