# Cannot get newtcolorbox to work properly

Tags: tcolorbox, cleveref

Here is a MWE:

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatexmk
\documentclass[11pt]{book} 

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}    
    \definecolor{lightcyan}{rgb}{0.88, 1.0, 1.0}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
    \tcbuselibrary{skins}   

\newcounter{abc}
\newtcolorbox
[%
use counter= abc,
number within=chapter,
Crefname={Box}{Boxes}
]
{mybox}
[2][]%
{%
detach title,
colback=lightcyan,
colframe=lightcyan,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
coltitle=black,
before upper={\tcbtitle\quad},
title={Bluebox \thetcbcounter.\hspace{2mm} #2, #1}
}%

\begin{document}
\chapter{ONE}
\section{one}

\begin{mybox}
Some text Some text Some text
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}[label={myreference}]{my title}
Some text Some text Some text
\end{mybox}

Reference: \Cref{myreference}

\end{document}
```

And here are the problems:

[image]

I am using `tcolorbox 3.80` under `osx 10.6.8` and tried to imitate the example on page 99.

The loading order for `tcolorbox` and `cleveref` does not seem to matter for the `Cref` issue.

Just in case it might be a clue, the commas after `S` in Bluebox1.1 and after `my title` in Blubox 1.2 disappear if I remove the comma after `#2` in the preamble.

Comment: Check the order of the `}` in the title definition of your `mybox`  ;-) The first usage of `mybox` does miss the mandatory second argument as well, see that the `S` of `Some` leaks into the title

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is the wrong placement of the `}` in the definition of the `mybox` environment:

The definition of the title

```
    title={Bluebox \thetcbcounter.\hspace{2mm} #2, #1}
```

is clearly wrong here, since it uses the optional argument `#1` in the title of the box

```
    title={Bluebox \thetcbcounter.\hspace{2mm} #2}, #1%
```

is correct, since the optional argument is made known to `tcolorbox` then, especially the `label=` option comes into action.

In addition, the first usage of `mybox` is wrong, since it misses an empty `{}` 2nd argument, the `S` of `Some` leaks into the title and is stripped. Use an empty `{}` here, however, this leaves a large space after the box number, since there's an explicit `\hspace` usage. (see the 'better' code at the end of this post!)

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatexmk
\documentclass[11pt]{book} 

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}    
    \definecolor{lightcyan}{rgb}{0.88, 1.0, 1.0}

\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newcounter{abc}
\newtcolorbox
[%
use counter= abc,
number within=chapter,
Crefname={Box}{Boxes}
]
{mybox}
[2][]%
{%
detach title,
colback=lightcyan,
colframe=lightcyan,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
coltitle=black,
before upper={\tcbtitle\quad},
title={Bluebox \thetcbcounter.\hspace{2mm} #2}, #1%
}%

\begin{document}
\chapter{ONE}
\section{one}

\begin{mybox}{}% Empty title!!!!
Some text Some text Some text
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}[label={myreference}]{my title}
Some text Some text Some text
\end{mybox}

Reference: \Cref{myreference}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update** Here's a way that checks for an empty title with `\notblank` from `etoolbox`

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatexmk
\documentclass[11pt]{book} 

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}    
    \definecolor{lightcyan}{rgb}{0.88, 1.0, 1.0}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newcounter{abc}
\newtcolorbox
[%
use counter= abc,
number within=chapter,
Crefname={Box}{Boxes}
]
{mybox}
[2][]%
{%
detach title,
colback=lightcyan,
colframe=lightcyan,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
coltitle=black,
before upper={\tcbtitle\quad},
title={Bluebox \thetcbcounter.\notblank{#2}{\hspace{2mm} #2}{}}, #1
}%

\begin{document}
\chapter{ONE}
\section{one}

\begin{mybox}{}
Some text Some text Some text
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}[label={myreference}]{my title}
Some text Some text Some text
\end{mybox}

Reference: \Cref{myreference}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I spent several hours looking for the error and would never have found it because I do not really understand `tcolorbox`. But it's me, `tcolorbox` is a fantastic package. Thanks for the detailed explanations---which I understood.

Comment: @schremmer: Yes, it is a fantastic package, but in this case, the error is not really related to the package at all. It's just a wrong positioning of the `}` ;-)

Comment: I see that, now, but for me it was all the same. But now I think I am beginning to understand. And, above, I meant to say that I do not understand `LaTeX`.

Comment: @schremmer: Yes. I forgot to mention: `cleveref` is one of the packages, that should be loaded last, even after `hyperref`

Comment: That it should be loaded after `hyperref` I learned the hard way already a while ago. But, I seem to remember that the doc for (a previous version of ?) `tcolorbox` mentioned that `tcolorbox` should be loaded after `cleveref`. (The other fantastic package.)

Comment: So now, I keep checking both orders as soon as I get into trouble but `tcolorbox` after `cleveref` seems to hold good. What is happening is that I am now using both packages for unifying a whole lot of things I was doing piecemeal in the magnum opus. Thanks again for your help past and present.

Comment: @schremmer: Can you give me the page number where you found this recommendation about the order of `cleveref` and `tcolorbox` loading?

Comment: I must have dreamt it. But, in searching for it, I found that you had already explained things to me. Sorry but grateful.

Comment: @schremmer: Perhaps it was stated this way in an older version of `tcolorbox`. Apparently it works with both variants anyways, so there's no trouble ahead :D

Comment: Finally got it. A bit confused. See `The \newtheorem commands have to come after the loading of cleveref`in the answer in [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19104/cleveref-with-counters-with-same-name].

Comment: @schremmer: Well, that's the definition of new theorems, not the loading of `cleverref` before or after `tcolorbox`. In any case, `cleveref` is already working at the moment `\newtheorem` is defining the relevant counters.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said "A bit confused". Right now, everything works well.