# Using \cref with consecutively numbered definitions and theorems

Tags: numbering, cleveref

I'd like to number definitions and theorems consecutively, and I'd like to reference them with package `cleveref`'s `\cref` command. Here's my attempt.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}[definition]{Theorem}

\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\crefname{definition}{def.}{defs.}
\crefname{theorem}{thm.}{thms.}
\begin{document}

\begin{definition}
Let $0$ denote the number zero.
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}\label{t:mytheorem}
Let $x$ be $0$. Then $x = 0$.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
Left for the reader.
\end{proof}

As can be seen in~\cref{t:mytheorem}, $x = 0$ whenever $x$ equals $0$.
\end{document}
```

[image: The definition and the theorem are numbered consecutively, but the citation is not worded correctly.]

The screenshot shows that the citation uses the wrong term 'def.'.

If I change the line

```
\newtheorem{theorem}[definition]{Theorem}
```

to

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
```

the citation is worded correctly, but the definition and the theorem are no longer numbered consecutively.

[image: Citation is worded correctly, but the definition and the theorem are not numbered consecutively.]

Comment: Possibly related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19104/cleveref-with-counters-with-same-name

Comment: In your case, the best solution is to load the`cleveref` package immediately after the `\usepackage{amsthm}` package and before the instruction `\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}`.