# Continuous {Theorem,Lemma,...} Numbering with cleveref

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, newtheorem

I want to have continuous numbering for all my theorem, lemma, etc environments, which wan be achieved with using a shared counter.

However this seems to break `cleveref`'s capability of referencing them by distinct names:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, mathtools}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[definition]{Example}
\usepackage[capitalise,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\crefname{example}{Example}{Examples}

\begin{document}
\begin{definition}\label{def}
Definition
\end{definition}

\begin{example}\label{ex}
Example
\end{example}

\cref{def}

\cref{ex}
\end{document}
```

This does produce the references `Definition 1` and `Definition 2`, instead of `Definition 1` and `Example 2`.

How can this be circumvented?

Comment: Closely related (possible dulicate?): [Cleveref with counters with same name](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19104/134144) To summarize: load `cleveref` after your `\newtheorem` commands.

Comment: Indeed, that fixes my problem! Thanks and sorry for the duplicate :/